# multiple animations like flash

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

The below code (I just gave a snippet of  working code) animates a few images based on time. Something like a Flash animation where at certain times images start to move at certain times or frame count. My question is , is there a better way to do this ? I know I can use something other than setInterval . I am calculating the elapsed time and setting off images based on the time interval.

It is the ClassLoadImages.prototype.m_draw which is the issue.

```
   function doGameLoop() {

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,400);
    now = new Date();

    totalSeconds = (now - start) / 1000;
    last = now;

    ctx.fillText("totalSeconds=" +totalSeconds ,10,100);
    if (totalSeconds>2 && totalSeconds<6)
    {
        img2.m_draw(130);
    }
    if (totalSeconds>4 && totalSeconds<8)
    {
        img3.m_draw2(230);
    }

    if (totalSeconds>10){
        start = new Date();//start again

    }
    img.m_draw(30);
  //  fi++;
 }



var img= new ClassLoadImages(30,30);
var img2= new ClassLoadImages(30,30);
var img3= new ClassLoadImages(30,30);
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried css3 animation on canvas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like flash movieclips, check out SpriteClip on github. https://github.com/wolthers/SpriteClip.js